# Can't make changes to word document opened as read-only

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, read-only, documents, microsoft-word-365

I've some documents on a network share that are password protected.

I need to open those files, make some temporary changes and then print them. Since I don't want those changes to be saved, I'm used to opening the files as read-only (image 1) to avoid accidental saves.
[image: image 1 - password or read-only prompt]

Since a few days ago an Office update seems to have made it so that when you open a file as read only all editing is disabled, and there's a dropdown on the top right of the ribbon, between the share and feedback buttons, that has all the options greyed except for viewing (image 2, except the first two options are disabled).
[image: image 2 - editing dropdown]

Does anyone know of a way to revert this change and allow temporary editing of read-only files?

**Extra info:**

- This is not an issue with the documents. Already tested it with old
  documents that used to work fine, but that now also open with editing
  disabled.
- This is not an issue with protected view. I have protected view
  completely disabled.
- The documents are not blocked in the file system    because of being
  downloaded from the internet (they are always created and    kept on a
  network share).
- The files have no read-only or similar file system properties. I've
  full access to them.
- Word version is *Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2211
  Build 16. 0. 15831. 20098) 64-bit* and Windows version is *Windows 10 Pro 22H2 build 19045.2364*.

Thank you for your help.

**What we know so far about this issue:**

- I've been able to confirm with others that this is not an isolated issue and is the new default behaviour in the most recent word versions.
- The new behaviour was added on a mid December 2022 update for Office.
- Filling forms in the documents is also blocked.
- It seems like this change was only made to docx files, so saving the file as a dotx (word template) works as a temporary solution.

Comment: I think you're mistaking that this is new. **Read Only** by definition means ***You cannot make changes to it***!

Comment: Another note, from your 2nd screenshot ("Open in Desktop App" option) it's clear that this is being viewed now using Word Online (not the Word Desktop app.) Maybe try to actually open it in the Word Desktop App.

Comment: @YisroelTech I'm sure this is new, I've been doing this everyday for more than 20 years. You have always been able make changes to a document opened as read-only, you just couldn't save it with the same name unless you entered the write password. Also the second image is not a screenshot, it just an example from google images since my system is in PT and would make it harder to understand. As I mentioned in the Extra Info I'm using Word for desktop.

Comment: @YisroelTech That's not how it has always worked. At one time, you could set a read and write password for a Word document. If you didn't provide the write password when you opened the document, you could choose the Read Only option, and at that point you could get to a point where you could edit the document as normal - you just couldn't save it. However, that has been changing with Office 365/Microsoft 365. Now, it doesn't seem to be possible even to open documents in that way. But I couldn't tell you when that all changed or whether there are settings that allow the older behaviour.

Comment: @jonsson thank you for validating what I'm saying, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: @BlindSpots, he already responded that he is actually using the desktop app, just that the screenshot was from what he found online (since he can't screenshot his.)

Comment: I have confirmed the behavior as well.  It's a bit odd given that you can open the same  *read only* documents in Google Docs without a prompt and make any changes you want and print or save the changed document.  Seems to ignore the read only protection in my test using "Password Protection."  "User Authentication" mode not tested but likely fails due to file encryption.

Comment: Just to add more info to this, I've been able to confirm with others that this is not an isolated issue and that it appeared in a December Office update.

Comment: A bit of advice,,, please add new / updated / clarifying info directly into the question by editing it instead of commenting. This way the relevant info is directly available for the community members without a need of browsing through extended comment discussions.

Comment: @Peregrino69 It was already in the original question, the comment was just to trigger a notification for anyone following the issue.

Comment: Ah, a bump :) I added anyway the "I've confirmed with others" to the question.